# Drawing and Graphics from a C++ .dll within Python C-types

Tags: python, c#, c++, graphics

I'm getting quite good marshalling c++ DLLs into Python with ctypes. My company has existing C++ .dlls that handle fingerprint authentication and such, but my codebase is Python, they can also use the DLLs with C#. I got most of the data back from the DLL, so know that the DLL can be successfully marshalled.

There is one call that allows you to draw an image of a fingerprint from a scan that has just happened on the reader. The function within the DLL (Draw Template) requires five variables, g, which is a Graphics instance, r, which is a Rectangle instance, template data, width and height.

Template data, width and height I understand, this is what I get from the other calls. I cannot figure out how to generate a Graphics instance or a Rectangle instance from within Python. Am I going to have to learn C#?

Some example code (in c#) that they gave me:

```
public static Bitmap DrawFeatures(byte[] templateData)
    {
        int width = 288;
        int height = 320;

        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, 288, 320);

        var B = new Bitmap(width, height);

        var g = Graphics.FromImage(B);

        var ret = UFExtractor.DrawTemplate(g, r, templateData, width, height);
        if (UFE_STATUS.OK != ret)
        {
            Debug.Write(string.Format("can not draw template(error code = {0}).", ret));
            return null;
        }
        return B;
    }
```

Is there any way to generate a Rectangle instance or Graphics instance within Python CTypes or am I also going to have to marshal an Image processing DLL?

Comment: There have to be .net wrappers for Python. I recommend a bit of Websearching to find one that suits you.

Comment: Side note: that example code is terrible. It's missing `using` and error handling.